# Definition of the score function.

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I'm reading the very good *All of Statistics* by Larry Wasserman and I have a doubt. How do you define the score function?

Wasserman defines it as:

$$s(X; p) = \frac{\partial \log f(x; p)}{\partial p}$$

where $f(x; p)$ is the probability density, while in wikipedia:

$$s = \frac{\partial}{\partial p} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\log f(x_i; p)$$

Perhaps, as **@Francisco** below noted, there's the equivalence $f(x;p) = \prod_{i=1}^{n}f(x_i;p)$, but I'm not so sure Wasserman uses that criterion. For instance, he gives the example of a $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n \sim \text{Bernoulli}(p)$. The score is

$$s(X; p) = \frac{X}{p} + \frac{1 - X}{1 - p}.$$

This is result you get if you calculate with respect to a single $X$ Bernoulli variable. If you do the calculation with the full set of $X_i$ (so you use the wikipedia definition) you get a different result. For instance, if you want to calculate the maximum likelihood estimator, you need to take into account all the $X_{i}$, so why do you use only one $X$ for the score function? This seems like unnatural for me.

**In other words:** How would you do the case of the Bernoulli distribution above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

but $$f(x;p) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} f(x_i; p) $$ no? ... so both definitions are actually the same. I do not see the difference, the log of a product is the sum of the logs...

Comment: Yes, that's the property of the logarithms, but the problem is that I'm not so sure that in the book $f(x; p) = \prod_{i=1}^{n}f(x_i; p)$. When he solves the example I give, the Bernoulli case, he does it as a single variable $X$, he does not sum nor he does the product. So that's what bothers me. If you calculate the maximum likelihood estimator, for instance, you use the full set of $X_i$ variables... (I edit my question)

Comment: if we set $X = \frac{X_1 + \cdots X_n}{n}$ the equations holds for independent trials...